Bias transistor for digital signal decoupling source (composite video amp)
Short question first
If I want to use an emitter-follower to strengthen a signal source and I need a bias network for the transistor, how do I isolate this from the source if the source is digital?
Context:
I am dealing with a 70s console system and trying to get composite video out of it (used to have only RF out). I've managed to mix the signal I need with all of the sync and brightness components and I have it in the 0V to 1V peak to peak, the problem is that it's a weak signal, so when I connect it to any composite video monitor, which I understand has an impedance of 75 ohms, the signal dies, which I can confirm with my oscilloscope.
I understand that a common way to strengthen a signal is by simply using a transistor in Emitter-Follower configuration, getting a gain of 1, which is effectively what I want. I have done this biasing the transistor to the desired region, and it "almost" works.
The "almost" part is because the source signal is part analog, part digital. The brightness part, what is displayed on the screen, is just like an AC signal, but the sync pulses are, for the duration of the pulse, DC. In the case of this system the vertical sync cheats and keeps the pulse for longer rather than following the specification, which just worked with the TVs at the time, so it's not a short pulse. This is relevant because when I try to put a capacitor to decouple the source signal from the bias network, it has a noticeable effect on these pulses. I've managed to find cap values by which I get a decent output on the screen, but I do see some side effects, the image is not clean. If I don't put a cap, I can't get it to work, and I'm assuming that the bias network is messing up with the source, but I don't know enough to accurately diagnose this. All sync parts of the signal before getting to the amplification point go through diodes, which made me thing that this setup could work without the decoupling cap, but it doesn't.
I've seen designs of people using op-amps for this, but before going down that route I wanted to confirm if there's something inherently impossible with solving the problem the way I was trying to do it.

Would you please include a circuit diagram of what you have achieved so far? It would greatly help us understand your problem.

Please post scope waveforms of the signal you are trying to buffer, without your buffer attached, under these conditions: 1. Unloaded, ie not connected to the comp video input of the monitor.  2. Loaded. Also attach schematic of your buffer.

If your problem is as you write, that "the bias network is messing up with the source," then you should explain in detail what the source is, otherwise no-one can tell you what the problem is.

For proper driving a 75 ohm cable you need 2 V amplitude and a series resistor of 75 ohm at the output. So a gain of 2 is required if you want to implement this with proper termination.
